# How do I convert Nm/Kg in MGOe?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

i have to buy a few magnets of a certain attraction intensity, i would like to know how to convert Nm / Kg in MGOe. What is the formula? Can you please make an example for 100 Nm/Kg?

Comment: Note: I meant Nm / Kg2

Answer (score 1):

MGOe (megagauss-oersted) is a unit for the density of energy stored in a magnet, and it is also called *maximum energy product, abbreviated BH<sub>max</sub>* (See this Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oersted#Stored_energy)). It has the dimensions M L<sup>-1</sup> T<sup>-2</sup>.

Since this is energy density (per unit volume) we are talking about, it can also be represented as J/m<sup>3</sup>, i.e. Nm/m<sup>3</sup>. We could convert this to energy per unit mass by dividing this value with the mass density, which would give us a value with units (Nm/m<sup>3</sup>)÷(kg/m<sup>3</sup>), i.e. Nm/kg.

Since one MGOe is approximately 7957.75 Nm/m<sup>3</sup>, if you know the mass density of the material of the magnets you are buying, you can use that to find out the MGOe from Nm/kg.

For 100 Nm/kg, the energy stored per unit mass,

$BH_{max,mass} = 100\,Nm/kg$

Assuming a density of 7200 kg/m<sup>3</sup>, the energy stored per unit volume,

$BH_{max} = 100\,Nm/kg×7200\,kg/m^3 = 720\,000\,Nm/m^3$

This in MGOe,

$BH_{max} = 720\,000\,Nm/m^3÷7957.75\,\{(Nm/m^3)/MGOe\} = 90.4778\,MGOe $

Comment: thank you @Hari G.  or the very accurate answer, can you please give me also the formula for Nm/kg2, I'm very bad in math!

Comment: @robert-falco I do not think Nm/kg^2 corresponds to any sensible form of energy density.

Comment: I'm using a software that is called Algodoo, it's a software of applied physics, this program uses this measure unit for linear attraction and for quadratic attraction  Nm2 / Kg2.

Comment: Take a look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant).

Comment: It uses Nm/Kg2 because it's a 2d software, I know that the 3d world is different, what  should i do then? Do i have to consider that the thickness of the magnet is equal to 1 to compare Nm / Kg2 to Nm /kg3 ? Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: i found this "The density in Algodoo corresponds to real-world units g/cm³ or kg/dm³ if one assumes objects in Algodoo are 1 mm thick.";

Comment: sorry if i bother you, but I have a last question: in this case, having the object 1mm thick, if i'm correct Nm/Kg2 coresponds to Nm/Kg3 ?